Automating vsce login and Publishing VS Code Extensions in CI/CD Pipelines
I'm trying to automate the publishing of a Visual Studio Code extension in a CI/CD pipeline (Azure DevOps). I am using the vsce tool, but I encounter issues with automating the vsce login  step, which requires user interaction (Y/N confirmation and a Personal Access Token (PAT)).
Despite trying this, the pipeline fails with the following error:
WARNING  Failed to open credential store. Falling back to storing secrets clear-text in: /home/vsts/.vsce
ERROR  The Personal Access Token verification has failed. Additional information:
TF400813: The user 'aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa' is not authorized to access this resource.

What I've Tried:
Pre-authenticating locally and using stored credentials in the pipeline.
Setting the PAT as an environment variable and automating the input using echo.
Ensuring that the PAT has the Marketplace (Publish) scope and double-checking the publisherName.
Questions:
Is there a way to skip the vsce login step by directly passing the PAT to vsce publish, or does vsce provide a --pat option for this?
If not, what is the best way to fully automate vsce login in CI/CD pipelines while ensuring security and avoiding manual intervention?
Additional Context:
My pipeline is running on a Linux-based Azure DevOps agent.
The PAT I’m using has both Marketplace (Publish) and Packaging (Read & Write) permissions.
I'm looking for a secure solution to streamline the publishing process.
Any guidance, suggestions, or working examples of automating this process would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
I tried the following approach to automate the interaction, but it doesn't work for me:
PUBLISHER_NAME="your_publisher_name"
PAT="your_personal_access_token"

# Automate the interaction
echo -e "y\n$PAT" | vsce login $PUBLISHER_NAME


